# Converting string in host character encoding to Unicode in C

Tags: c, unicode, encoding

Is there a way to **portably** (that is, conforming to the C standard) convert strings in the host character encoding to an array of Unicode code points?  I'm working on some data serialization software, and I've got a problem because while I need to send UTF-8 over the wire, the C standard doesn't guarantee the ASCII encoding, so converting a string in the host character encoding can be a nontrivial task.

Is there a library that takes care of this kind of stuff for me?  Is there a function hidden in the C standard library that can do something like this?

Comment: No, nothing in the C standard library, but you might want to read about [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: are you taking into account C11 and the `<uchar.h>` header?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, I haven't been reading up on C11 as much as I want to, so there may be quite a lot in it that I missed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That library seems to have exactly the utilities I'm looking for, but it's wayyyy too heavyweight for my purposes.  Do you know of any simpler libraries that are also capable of handling these types of conversions?

Comment: Are you sure "the host character encoding" is well-defined and correct?  The assumption that an undeclared, untyped user-supplied character string is in a particular character encoding inevitably leads to [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Answer (score 2):

The C11 standard, ISO/IEC 9899:2011, has a new header `<uchar.h>` with rudimentary facilities to help.  It is described in section **§7.28 Unicode utilities `<uchar.h>`**.

There are two pairs of functions defined:

- `c16rtomb()` and `mbrtoc16()` — using type `char16_t` aka `uint_least16_t`.
- `c32rtomb()` and `mbrtoc32()` — using type `char32_t` aka `uint_least32_t`.

The `r` in the name is for 'restartable'; the functions are intended to be called iteratively.  The `mbrtoc{16,32}()` pair convert from a multibyte code set (hence the `mb`) to either `char16_t` or `char32_t`.  The `c{16,32}rtomb()` pair convert from either `char16_t` or `char32_t` to a multibyte character sequence.

I'm not sure whether they'll do what you want. The `<uchar.h>` header and hence the functions are not available on Mac OS X 10.9.1 with either the Apple-provided `clang` or with the 'home-built' GCC 4.8.2, so I've not had a chance to investigate them.  The header does appear to be available on Linux (Ubuntu 13.10) with GCC 4.8.1.

I think it likely that [ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/) is a better choice — it is, however, a rather large library (but that is because it does a thorough job of supporting Unicode in general and different locales in general).